# Devise ng-token-auth bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I use devise-token-auth, and when I click on the link inside my confirmation mail, I got the error:

`bad argument (expected URI object or URI string`)

When I do a get request with this route

```
auth/confirmation/?confirmation_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I have try a lot of thing that I could found on internet and I find nothing that can work.

I have generate ng-token-auth views but that change nothing.

Does anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
  confirmations:      'devise_token_auth/confirmations',
  passwords:          'devise_token_auth/passwords',
  omniauth_callbacks: 'devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks',
  registrations:      'devise_token_auth/registrations',
  sessions:           'devise_token_auth/sessions',
  token_validations:  'devise_token_auth/token_validations'
}
    get '/google_api' => 'google_api#index'

end
```

rake routes

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /auth/sign_in(.:format)                devise_token_auth/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /auth/sign_in(.:format)                devise_token_auth/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /auth/sign_out(.:format)               devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /auth/password(.:format)               devise_token_auth/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /auth/password/new(.:format)           devise_token_auth/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /auth/password/edit(.:format)          devise_token_auth/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /auth/password(.:format)               devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                         PUT    /auth/password(.:format)               devise_token_auth/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /auth/cancel(.:format)                 devise_token_auth/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /auth/sign_up(.:format)                devise_token_auth/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /auth/edit(.:format)                   devise_token_auth/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#update
                         PUT    /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#update
                         DELETE /auth(.:format)                        devise_token_auth/registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /auth/confirmation(.:format)           devise_token_auth/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /auth/confirmation/new(.:format)       devise_token_auth/confirmations#new
                         GET    /auth/confirmation(.:format)           devise_token_auth/confirmations#show
     auth_validate_token GET    /auth/validate_token(.:format)         devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
            auth_failure GET    /auth/failure(.:format)                devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                         GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)     devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_success
                         GET    /omniauth/:provider/callback(.:format) devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#redirect_callbacks
        omniauth_failure GET    /omniauth/failure(.:format)            devise_token_auth/omniauth_callbacks#omniauth_failure
                         GET    /auth/:provider(.:format)              redirect(301)
              google_api GET    /google_api(.:format)                  google_api#index
```

Comment: That route doesn't look quite right. Could it be auth/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcd? Please include your routing code as well

Comment: Same error and edited :)